# Are extensions ignored in makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

A `cube.c` is stored in the folder cube. makefile is as follows

```
LDFLAGS=-lglut -lGLU

all: cube
```

Could anyone help me solve the following questions?

- `cube` means cube.c? why does `cube` have no extension `.c`?
- There is no command after the line `all: cube`, and `LDFLAGES` is not used. Why can it be written in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cube means cube.c? why does cube have no extension .c?

It's the name of the resulting executable.

> There is no command after the line all: cube, and LDFLAGES is not
>   used.

`LDFLAGS` is used in implicit rules

> - n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`
> - n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually
>     called ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)`

See [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

Comment: Where can I find these implicit rules? I read some tutorials but all of them use explicit command.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules

Answer (score 1):

`cube` is the executable itself. Your `make` probably has built-in rules for compiling a `.c` file to `.o` file (using `CFLAGS`) and for linking a single `.o` file (using `LDFLAGS`) to an executable. So all you have to do is supply the `LDFLAGS` and give `make` at least one target and that target is conventionally called `all`.

If you explicitly write out the rules that `make` can infer, you'd have something like this:

```
CC=cc
CFLAGS=
LDFLAGS=-lglut -lGLU

all: cube

cube: cube.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) cube cube.o

cube.o: cube.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c cube.c
```

The GNU Make manual has a section on its implicit rules:

> http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Implicit-Rules.html